# carto sidebar not showing

Tags: carto

just started learning how to use carto using the tutorial [HERE](https://carto.com/academy/courses/beginners-course/your-first-choropleth-map/). My sidebar isnt shown anywhere on my dashboard. How do i find this so that i can continue with the tutorial[image].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial is outdated. You need to [go to the new CARTO Learn website](https://carto.com/learn/guides) for updated guides and documentation.